# Value of determinant using given conditions.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a $2$ x $2$ matrix with real entries and $det(A)$ is equal to $d$ which is non-zero. It is given that $det(A +d(adjA))=0$ where $adj$ stands for the adjoint of the matrix. We have to find the value of $det(A-d(adjA))$.

My approach was to assume a matrix with 4 real entries and then apply the given conditions. It did yield the required answer, but I think there may be a better method to do this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: when you talk about adjoint, you mean that $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{d}(\text{adj}(A))^T$?

Comment: For matrices $A,B$ of order two we have the formula  $det(A+B)=det(A)+det(B)+tr(Aadj(B))$.

Comment: @the_candyman: Adjoint is also called as adjugate, I guess.